# MySQL calculate an complicated expression

Tags: sql, mysql

i have 2 fields in database and i would like to find the difference of them in percentage.
So mathematical the formula should be

```
ABSOLUTE((field1-field2)/(MAXIMUM(field1, field2)))
```

the problem is I dont know how to ask for maximum of 2 numbers. Since MAX in sql returns the max of column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  ABS(field1 - field2) / GREATEST(field1, field2)
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe someting like:

```
if (field1 > field2, (field1 - field2)/field1, (field2 - field1) / field1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply this

```
ABS((field1-field2)/(GREATEST(field1, field2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an IF:

`SELECT IF(field1 < field2, field1, field2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the function named GREATEST, since MAX is used elsewhere in SQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest